# Cross reference another table before import?

Tags: mysql, csv, import, load-data-infile

I'm trying to build a master scrub list for my email campaigns. The table contains only 3 fields: email, reason, and a timestamp for when it was added. As far as I'm concerned, it doesn't matter to me whether the email has bounced, unsubscribed, or processed through a feedback loop. The bottom line is I don't want to send to the emails in this table ever again for any reason.

When I import lists into my mailing system, I want to cross reference this "scrub" table before it is imported to the main table containing current customers. So far I can easily import email lists into the database using:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'/home/domain/tmp/temp_file' 
INTO TABLE `master_email_list` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ';' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

How can I "check" the `master_scrub` table BEFORE it imports into the main `master_email_list` table?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is just an ascii file, you export all emails from your scrub table as file1, and do a fgrep -v -f file1 temp_file > temp_file2, which should have excluded all your scrub table entries. This assumes your os is unix. In windows you can do the same with powershell.